# SQL Dealing with NULL Values

Tags: sql, null

I have a quick question when dealing with null values in a table. I'm trying to sum up all sales made by each sales person below:

| Person | Product | Price |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Bob | Prod1 | 10.99 |
| Sue | Prod1 | 10.99 |
| Bob | Prod1 |  |
| Anna | Prod2 | 50.99 |

In this case, Bob didn't enter his price and left it null but it would be the same 10.99 value. How would I write a query that delivers total sales by sales person like below:

| Person | Product | Price |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Bob | Prod1 | 21.98 |
| Sue | Prod1 | 10.99 |
| Anna | Prod2 | 50.99 |

Comment: I need the query to pull forward the last non-null value for Prod1 so that I can do:
SELECT
Person,
SUM(Price) AS PriceSum
FROM
Table
GROUP BY
Person

Comment: Replace the nulls with the average price per product first. Then run that SQL command.

Answer (score 1):

You could use *max* (or min or avg) as a windowed aggregate to replace the nulls per person & product:

```
Select Person, Product, sum(Price) Price
from (
    select person, product, 
      Coalesce(price, Max(price) over(partition by person, product)) Price
    from t
)t
group by person, product
```

Answer (score 0):

`SELECT Person, SUM(Price) AS PriceSum FROM Table GROUP BY Person` should give you the desired results since you're grouping by Person they would be aggregated under **Bob**